# Generate progress bar in modal in shiny app, that closes automatically

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, progress-bar

I am working on a shiny app that takes a long time to do calculations, I want to have a modal progress bar that closes automatically as soon as all calculations work.

The ideal solution would have two features

1. Covers most of the screen and prevents the user to interact with app
2. Closes automatically as soon as it finishes making calulations

I found this solution in the following question:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Launch long calculation"), #, onclick = "$('#my-modal').modal().focus();"

  # You can open the modal server-side, you have to put this in the ui :
  tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('launch-modal', function(d) {$('#' + d).modal().focus();})"),
  tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('remove-modal', function(d) {$('#' + d).modal('hide');})"),

  # Code for creating a modal
  tags$div(
id = "my-modal",
class="modal fade", tabindex="-1", `data-backdrop`="static", `data-keyboard`="false",
tags$div(
  class="modal-dialog",
  tags$div(
    class = "modal-content",
    tags$div(class="modal-header", tags$h4(class="modal-title", "Calculation in progress")),
    tags$div(
      class="modal-body",
      shinyWidgets::progressBar(id = "pb", value = 0, display_pct = TRUE)
    ),
    tags$div(class="modal-footer", tags$button(type="button", class="btn btn-default", `data-dismiss`="modal", "Dismiss"))
  )
)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   value <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    shinyWidgets::updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "pb", value = 0) # reinitialize to 0 if you run the calculation several times
session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'launch-modal', "my-modal") # launch the modal
    # run calculation
    for (i in 1:10) {
      Sys.sleep(0.5)
      newValue <- value() + 1
      value(newValue)
      shinyWidgets::updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "pb", value = 100/10*i)
}
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    # session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'remove-modal', "my-modal") # hide the modal programmatically
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This solves issue 1, but I have to click on dismiss to see the results

Comment: Why not uncomment the last line in the observeEvent? It closes the modal when it hits 100%.  This one: `session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'remove-modal', "my-modal")`

Comment: @SeGa I did that but it did not work

Comment: It worked for me. Are you on the latest shiny version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original `progressbar` provided in `shiny` is exactly what you need.

But I use `css` to make the `progessbar` display in the middle in the screen.

You can find the detail of using progress bar in shiny [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html).

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Launch long calculation"), #, onclick = "$('#my-modal').modal().focus();"

  # css to center the progress bar
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML(".shiny-notification {
           height: 100px;
           width: 800px;
           position:fixed;
           top: calc(50% - 50px);
           left: calc(50% - 400px);
           font-size: 250%;
           text-align: center;
           }
           "
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  value <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    withProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress', value = 0,detail="0%", {
      # run calculation
      for (i in 1:10) {
        Sys.sleep(0.5)
        newValue <- value() + 1
        value(newValue)
        incProgress(1/10,detail = paste0(i*10,"%"))
      }
      Sys.sleep(0.5)
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hello @JimChen your answer works, I want to upvote it and select it, but could you take out the modal code, I copied your answer and it worked, but I realized that all the modal code and the shinywidget package is not necesarry in your answer, it may confuse other users. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @JimChen, I have a question for you, do you know a way to add to the css a dark transparent background that covers the app while it works (like the modal), that would be an extra

Answer (score 3):

Not a whole answer, just answering the additional css requests. You could change the css to, which will make the panel fill up the whole page.

```
.shiny-notification {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position:fixed;
  font-size: 250%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
}
```